# How to transform local coordinates to JavaFX chart coordinates

Tags: java, javafx, charts

For a business application it is a requirement for users to be able to select a certain part of a JavaFX LineChart. Currently I've got the selection box working using the onMousePressed, onMouseDragged and onMouseReleased listeners in combination with a JavaFX Rectangle and some coordinate magic. When I do .getX() and .getY() on these events I get the appropriate coordinates for drawing the Rectangle on the chart. These are the coordinates relative to the JavaFX chart I assume?

When a user has made a selection this rectangle overlays the chart and allows the user to do whatever they want with their selection or draw a new selection. This all works but when a user starts to draw from within the previous selection this takes the coordinates relative to the Rectangle. My question is as follows: how do I make the Rectangle "transparent" for mouse events and send these events to the underlying component (the LineChart). Or is there a way to transform these coordinates to the LineChart coordinates.

Please note that I have already tried localToParent, localToScene followed by sceneToLocal and sceneToLocal on all different parts. Also I have tried to change pickOnBounds differently even though I am not fully aware of the exact working of that property.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently I've got the selection box working using the onMousePressed, onMouseDragged and onMouseReleased listeners in combination with a JavaFX Rectangle and some coordinate magic. When I do .getX() and .getY() on these events I get the appropriate coordinates for drawing the Rectangle on the chart. These are the coordinates relative to the JavaFX chart I assume?

No, it is not relative to the chart, it is local co-ordinates of the target node that you clicked on.  See the documentation for [MouseEvent::getX](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html):

> Horizontal position of the event relative to the origin of the
>   MouseEvent's source.

The chart is a complex thing made up of many nodes and panes, each of which can have their own local co-ordinate system. So what getX will return will depend upon the actual thing which you are clicking on.  For example if you overlay a translucent filled Rectangle on top of the chart, then click inside the rectangle, the co-ordinates are going to be local co-ordinates within the rectangle.

> how do I make the Rectangle "transparent" for mouse events and send these events to the underlying component (the LineChart).

Make the rectangle [mouse transparent](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent(boolean)):

```
rectangle.setMouseTransparent(true);
```

> Or is there a way to transform these coordinates to the LineChart coordinates.

You can get use calls like [`mouseEvent.getSceneX()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#getSceneX())
 to get scene co-ordinates, rather than local co-ordinates.

You can then transform the co-ordinates into local co-ordinates of any node you wish using [`node.sceneToLocal(sceneX, sceneY)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#sceneToLocal(double,double)):

```
node.sceneToLocal(mouseEvent.getSceneX(), mouseEvent.getSceneY());
```

So, as long as you have a reference to the relevant node within the line chart for which you want to determine the relative co-ordinates of the mouse click, you can do that.

Comment: The rectangle.setMouseTransparent(true); does exactly what I needed to do and I feel stupid for not finding this myself after two days of reading documentation, thank you so much. Answer approved :)